# Converting Linear Combination to GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

How would I convert a linear combination to a GCD? I was told to use the Euclidean Algorithm and I know how to convert from GCD to linear combination, but not the reverse.

Edit: linear combination as in $ax+by=c$ given $a$, $b$, and $c$ and assuming all values are integer values

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "linear combination"? Could you give us an example?

Comment: This is fairly vague question. Can you be more specific? It is true that if $a,b$ are integer then there are integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b).$

Comment: Edited the post to give more details

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,e:=c/d\,$ times $\,\gcd(a,b)=d \Rightarrow  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\gcd(ae,be) = c}\,\ $  Note $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid c=ax\!+\!by$